# How to set up a backbone model, and it's view without defining a collection? Currently have empty request payload

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I thought I had the *Model*, *ModelView*, *Collection*, *AppView* [sample on github/documentcloud/backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/tree/master/examples/todos) reasonably understood, until..

I tried to set up something that is more cut-down. I'm trying to just have a `Model` and a `View`.

#### My issue

> The post of data does not work; **the request payload in the network trace is empty**, what have I missed?

I have the **complete code up** on [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NickJosevski/DLsZQ/6/) *(A)*. I also tested that the sample code that works in my enviroment also works in [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NickJosevski/JGj8j/) *(B)* and network inspection shows that the request payload has data.

#### Model and View code

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/m',
});

window.MView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#template').html()),
    el: $('#modelfields'),

    initialize: function () { this.model.bind('change', this.render, this); },

    events: {
        "click .save": function () { this.model.save(); }
    },
    render: function () { 
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
});

window.MyMView = new MView({model: new MyModel});
```

#### Network window screen shots

- (A) [Response data empty on my sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2LRW.png)
- (B) [The official demo works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr6XN.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model has no properties! Set some defaults or call this.model.set({..}) to add them.

I've updated your example to include a default value and the fields from the form.

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'defaultvalue':'somedefault'                                     
    },
    urlRoot: '/api/m',
});

window.MView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#template').html()),
    el: $('#modelfields'),

    initialize: function () { this.model.bind('change', this.render, this); },

    events: {
        "click .save": 'save'
    },
    save: function() {
        var description = this.$("#Description").val();
        var moreData = this.$("#MoreData").val();
        this.model.set({"description":description,"more":moreData});
        this.model.save();            
    },
    render: function () { 
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
});

window.MyMView = new MView({model: new MyModel});
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I think about it and look at the samples, this looks to be the common approach. Your serialize suggestion also sounds like an option.

Comment: Yep, for forms I use a snippet to extend jQuery.serialize to serialize to JSON and often bind to a form change event to keep the model up-to-date (the later is not advisable in all scenarios) https://gist.github.com/1991640

Comment: shouldn't we be using like this? {model: new MyModel()} instead of {model: new MyModel}